# Sublime Text : SQLTools Connection without specifying a database

Tags: mysql, sublimetext3

I'm configuring Sublime to run my SQL queries, I installed the SQLTools package and successfully connected to my host, however I need to specify a database and I don't want that, I want it to connect to all databases on that host , this in order for the autocomplete to work for all the databases, since if I connect to a specific db, the autocomplete only works for the Tables of that db.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSYx3.png)

When trying to omit the database attribute, the connection is not created correctly, so I suppose the database parameter must be there and I would like to know if there is a possibility of specifying that it take all.

PD: This is the way SQLTools is setting by default.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDqAu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.